# Task.Factory.StartNew won't wait for task completion?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've found that the following code won't actually wait for the task client.SendAsync() if I use the implementation:

```
taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Program().Foo()));
```

If I change it from `Task.Factory.StartNew()` to just `new Program().Foo()` or `Task.Run(() => new Program.Foo()` it will correctly output some information. What are the differences between the two?

```
internal class Program
{
    private async Task Foo()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, "http://www.google.com");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task>();

        // This won't output anything.
        taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Program().Foo()));

        // This will.
        taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => new Program().Foo()));

        // So does this.
        taskList.Add(new Program().Foo());

        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Based on [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx), it seems `Task.Run(someAction);` is equivalent to `Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);`

But even when I change the code to this, it won't output anything. Why?

```
internal class Program
{
    private async Task Foo()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, "http://www.google.com");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task>();
        taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Program().Foo(), CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default));
        //taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => new Program().Foo()));
        //taskList.Add(new Program().Foo());
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer of the question in subject line - No, unless you ask for.

Comment: Have a look to the async/await pattern. This will broad your horizon around this issue.

Comment: @derekhh: Read [your whole reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx). The part you're quoting is prefixed with **When you pass an Action to Task.Run**, which your code is not doing. Further down the blog post he explains how `Task.Run` behaves differently with asynchronous delegates.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem lays in the fact that `Task.Factory.StartNew` isn't "task aware". Meaning, the return type from your method call to `StartNew` is actually a `Task<Task>`. This means that you're only waiting on the *outter task* to complete, not the *inner one*.

A simple solution to that would be to use the [`TaskExtensions.Unwrap()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var taskList = new List<Task>();
    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Program().Foo()).Unwrap());

    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
}
```

`Task.Run` does work because it is "task aware". [It has an overload taking a `Func<Task>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382(v=vs.110).aspx), which internally calls `Unwrap` for you, returning only the inner task.

Comment: for a single task:

`var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(something);`
`task.Wait();`

Answer (score 3):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't await the completion of the inner task by default. If you create a variable with the return value, you will get this:

```
Task<Task> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Program().Foo());
```

This means that the delegate returns as soon as the inner task hits the await statement. You need to call `UnWrap` method to force the async execution:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Program().Foo()).Unwrap();
taskList.Add(task);
```

Blog post you posted also explains this difference between synchronous and asynchronous delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Your code waits for the end of `new Program().Foo()` with the statement `Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());`

However, `Foo` doesn't wait for the end of `client.SendAsync(requestMessage)` before returning, since it has an `await`. The await will let the method return the `Task` object and allow the thread to come back on the next line.

The "problem" is that since you return on your `await`, the task that calls the `Foo` method is complete is complete at that time, even before you hit the output on the command line (The Task *returned* by the `Foo` method however, is not complete).

You basically have 3 "timelines" (I won't say thread because I'm not sure the HttpClient actually starts a new thread, but if someone can confirm this, I'll edit the post.) and 2 tasks:

- your `Main` thread
- the task created with `StartNew`
- The the SendAsync task.

Your `Main` thread is waiting for the end of the Task created by `StartNew`, but that Task does **not** wait for the end of the `SendAsync` call, and therefore doesn't wait the command line output to consider itself as completed. Since only that one is considered in the `WaitAll` and the SendAsync isn't, it is normal that it returns that early.

To have the behaviour you want, you should have something like

```
taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Program().Foo().Wait()));
```

but then again, starting a new Task just to wait for another one wouldn't make much sense, so you'd better go with `taskList.Add(new Program().Foo());`